# Saving strings that contain empty variables for later use

Tags: php

Here goes again at my attempt at explaining, hopefully this is clearer. here is my core class.

```
function __construct() 
{



    $nav = array
    (
        "foo" => "bar",
        "foo" => "bar",
    );  


    $navBar = $var_dev->navBar;

    function navGenerator($navBar) 
    {

    return $navBar;

        /*foreach ($nav as $link_name => $link)
        {
        return $var_dev->navBar;
        //return '"<li><a href="'. $link_name . '">' . $link . '</a></li>';
        }*/

    }

}
```

Here is the other class where navBar is being called...

```
class standardHandle 
{
    public $navBar = 'lawl';
}
```

The above works fine, however I would like `$navBar = '<li><a href="'. $link_name . '">' . $link . '</a></li>'`

Comment: Sounds like you want a templating engine

Comment: Something like `strtr('<a href="#1#">#2#</a>', array('#1#' => 'http://', '#2#' => 'text'))`?

Comment: I am kind of trying to build my own templating engine (i think), ironically :S

Comment: Basically the error I am getting is because i am concatenating when defining a property.. also these variables are not defined, because they are defined in another class...

Comment: You need to instantiate the other class in your standardHandle class to access those variables. Lokk at the code that i have written to instantiate a class. If both the class are in different page, then you need to include the class first.

Comment: hmm okay, there wont be an infinite loop or recursive error if core instantiates standardHandle and standardHandle instantiates core??

Answer (score 0):

You can make two public variables in the core class. Now from the other class, you need to instantiate the core class and access those 2 variables and put values into it. eg.

**This is inregard to the question "I would like the core, to grab a string from the standardHandle that contains two variables."**

EDIT: I think i interchanged the class. But you get an idea how to access values from other classes.

```
class Coreclass {

       var $var1;
       var $var2;

       function someFunction() {


       }



}

//your other class

 class OtherClass {

       var $coreClass;

       function __construct() {
            $this->coreClass= new Coreclass () ;


            $this->coreClass->var1 = "somevalue";
            $this->coreClass->var2 = "someothervalue";
    }


 }
```

Comment: For what problem is this the solution? For "user had no idea about contexts"?

Comment: That was in regard to the question "I would like the core, to grab a string from the standardHandle that contains two variables."